# set cell focus in data grid view .NET

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, focus, cell

In my datagridview (Mydgv1),I want to set fourth cell into focus and edit it, after i leave the first cell.
On first cell's leave event , i have written the code to focus the 4th cell, it comes into focus, but there is no cursor in it, and then the focus shifts to second cell and second cell becomes blue(by default highlighted cell in datagridviews). Please post some code for it. So far I have tried this.

```
    Mydgv1.ClearSelection()
    Mydgv1.CurrentRow.Cells(3).Selected = True
    Mydgv1.BeginEdit(False)
```

Answer (score 1):

BeginEdit will only have effect on the current cell (marked by the CurrentCell property of the DataGridView object). Selecting it won't help (especially since you can select multiple cells in some DataGridView configurations). Instead try this:

```
    Dim ColumnIndex As Integer = 3

    Mydgv1.CurrentCell = Mydgv1.CurrentRow.Cells(ColumnIndex)
    Mydgv1.BeginEdit(False)
```

Comment: add some description to the answer.

Comment: You're right, I made it more clear by adding some explanation.